# using math.log to handle massive numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with a function that's something like (after evaluating the constants):

```
def n(x):
    return (1.416e-28)*(x**47)*(np.exp(-4.545*x))
```

X ranges from 0 to 20.  The x^47 term in the middle causes problems; even though the first and last terms get very small as x increases, the code overflows at x^47.

I've been able to get it to work by making the following modification:

```
def n(x):
    logn=math.log((1.416e-28)*(x**47)*(np.exp(-4.545*x)),x)
    return np.pow(r,logn)
```

This returns quite manageable numbers.

The problem is I'm trying to pass in a numpy array, but math.log only accepts scalars.  Furthermore, numpy doesn't seem to have a log function that accepts an arbitrary base.  Evidently the only way to do this in numpy is to do something like:

```
np.log(42**3)/np.log(42)
```

But it can't handle the large number in the first place without FIRST taking the log at base r.  So numpy won't work.

Should I just be un-pythonic and iterate through the n(x) fcn?

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do you compute `logn`, when you still need to compute the too-large number to pass as an argument to `math.log`, and 2) What is `r`?

Comment: Real (complex, even) multiplication is commutative, so you could break up the `x**47` term with something like `1.416e-28 * x**23 * np.exp(-4.545*x) * x**24`.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why `logn` works.  I'm guessing that math.log has some tricks such that it can manage gargantuan numbers, so long as the result is not gargantuan.  All I know is that it does work, having tried it on a couple of case numbers.  `bignumber(x)` fails, but math.log(`bignumber(x)`, x) works.  And that answers your second question; I meant to say `x` instead of `r`.

Comment: How are you detecting overflow? `math.log` is simply receiving whatever large number the expression evaluates to; it doesn't receive the expression itself.

Comment: ...It seemed that it worked, but on a second inspection I couldn't make it happen.  But your second comment works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to compute `x**47` in one go, break it up. Compute "half" of it, then let the partial product be reduced by multiplying by one of the small numbers before computing the "other half".

```
# Multiplications are computed left-to-right, so the partial
# product never gets too big.
return 1.416e-28 * x**23 * np.exp(-4.545*x) * x**24
```

Comment: You helped more than one person tonight.  Thanks 10**47!

Answer (score 2):

Since `ln(a*b) = ln(a) + ln(b)`, `ln(c**d) = d*ln(c)`, and `ln(exp(e*f)) = e*f`, you can rewrite your function as:

```
def n2(x):
    return np.exp(np.log(1.416e-28) + 47*np.log(x) - 4.545*x)
```

But having said that, I see no important difference in performance using either formulation:

```
>>> xx = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
>>> q = n(xx[1:])/n2(xx[1:])
>>> np.max(q)
1.0000000000000318
>>> np.min(q)
0.99999999999998357
```

Note the `xx[1:]` in the test. This is because `ln(0)` is undefined, leading to `nan` in `q[0]` if you pass `xx[0]` to `n2`.

BTW, the vector problem you mention in your post is because you're using `math.log` instead of `np.log`.

Comment: Right, I was aware of why the vector problem was happening...The issue is that NP doesn't seem to have a direct way of calculating an arbitrary base log.  However, I found that @chepner's solution works great (happened to help a colleague who's working on a similar project in Matlab, too!), so the log function isn't necessary.